The exact formula on relativistic electron degenerate pressure
I am studying white dwarf and I need relativistic electron degenerate pressure to calculate some physical problems like Chandrasekhar limit.
I only know that $p \approx n_e^{4/3}$ but the internet does not give me the exact formula.
Does anyone here know the formula?

I think you have to redo the calculations yourself. It is typically not presented in textbooks. There is no exact formula, but Taylor-like asymptotic expansions exist. Condensed matter textbooks may derive the NR QFT expansion and show that they work pretty well describing metals. You would have to adapt those computations for the SR case yourself.

@naturallyInconsistent I might be off here, but isn't the relativistic electron gas a standard problem in stat. mech. courses?

...and there is an exact formula, at least for $T=0$ (which sounds as a reasonable assumption given the comparably high $T_F$). and using a google search immediately gave the answer...

http://www.vikdhillon.staff.shef.ac.uk/teaching/phy213/phy213_degeneracy.html

@TobiasFünke: if you assume the electrons are non-relativistic then the $T = 0$ calculation is in many undergraduate textbooks. But to calculate the Chandrasekhar limit you need to go into the regime where the electrons are relativistic, which is a more involved calculation and not in the lower-level textbooks.

@MichaelSeifert With relativistic you mean that the energy dispersion is relativistic, no? I checked several books and the calculations always were done. But okay, might be "luck" or so. Anyway, as I said, using Google immediately gave me results with a detailed exact derivation.

@alanf Thanks! I found another at Statistical Mechanics Third Edition (R.K. Pathria, Paul D. Beale) Section 8.5 Equation (12)-(14), which is equal to $p = 1/8 \sqrt[3]{3/\pi}hcn_e^{4/3}$

Why not add your own answer?

TL, DR:
$$
p = (1 / 8) (3 / \pi)^{1/3} h c n_e^{4/3}
$$
Thanks to @alanf

Statistical Mechanics Third Edition (R.K. Pathria, Paul D. Beale) Section 8.5 Equation (12)-(15)
$$
p = \frac{\pi m^4 c^5}{3h^3}A(x)
$$
$$
A(x) = x\sqrt{x^2+1}(2x^2-3) + 3\sinh^{-1}x
$$
$$
x = (3n_e/8\pi)^{1/3}(h/mc)
$$
for non-relativistic electrons, $x \ll 1$, $A(x) \sim (8/5)x^5$
$$
p = (1 / 20) (3 / \pi)^{2/3} (h^2/m_e) n_e^{5/3}
$$
for relativistic electrons, $x \gg 1$, $A(x) \sim 2x^4$
$$
p = (1 / 8) (3 / \pi)^{1/3} h c n_e^{4/3}
$$
